# Use html for a symbol marker with arcgis api

Tags: esri, arcgis-js-api

I'm trying to add custom html marker in my layer renderer.

```
<div>
  <h1>Eg.</h1>
</div>
```

So far no success. From what I understand there's no way to do it but maybe someone has found a workaround.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-symbols-MarkerSymbol.html

```
layer.renderer = {
  type: "simple", 
  symbol: {
    type: "simple-marker", <-- this would be "html"
    outline: {
      width: 0.5,
      color: "white"
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for the whole `renderer`?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Is there a reason you spefically want html markup and not a [TextSymbol](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-symbols-TextSymbol.html)?

Comment: I want to render a dynamic component based on the $features with images

Comment: Hmmm...to get your desired effect you may need to look into multiple symbol layers in a [CIMSymbol](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-symbols-CIMSymbol.html).  You can use a SimpleMarkerSymbol for the background / frame, some TextSymbols, and a PictureMarkerSymbol to create the same effect as a div with a title and image.  I agree with you though that an 'HTMLSymbol' would be useful.

Comment: You might also consider formatting these as popups instead, as its easier to accomplish what you want with a popup.  You could make it so that the popups are automatically open, or opened when their source is in the map view.  Just an idea.

Comment: I thought about that too. I will give a try! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same scene and referred to this：

[git repository](https://github.com/nickcam/FlareClusterLayer)

[demo](https://flareclusterlayer.azurewebsites.net/index_v4.html)